# Access-Control-Allow-Origin from XML Request on Controller in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've been doing hours of research into this over the day and so far all the answers I run into have to do with working with WebAPI.  Unfortunately that's not an option for me.  The issue is there's an iframe on the site that refers to an older legacy version of a web application.  I need to be able to send a ajax call from that legacy version, have it get the data, and bring it back.  I can't use jsonp either, because the data is an actual actionresult, a full html page that would be being loaded into a div.   Any suggestions on other methods of setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin that are not involved with WebAPI?  I can't just set it -inside- of the controller, I have to be able to set it for a controller before the controller is hit.  It never even gets inside the controller right now.

My ajax call is something like this at the moment though I've tried multiple iterations with gets, json, et cetera:

```
$.ajax(function() {
  url: 'NotTheActualWebAddressObviously',
  cache: false,
  data: {
       variables: values
  },
  success: function (data) {
      // This isn't really all that important because it never gets here currently.
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to have a proxy at your server that refers to the other server. Cross domain restrictions do not apply to requests that originate from a server.

In other words, your ajax request from A instead of going to B, goes to A and A calls B.